# AngularJS : $pristine for ng-check checked inputs

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-model

I have a form with about 100 questions, each with a radio and some checkboxes, so I need the user to be able to save the form and load it later. I need also to check which ones the user changed in this session.

This question solves the problem: [How can I denote which input fields have changed in AngularJS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18641618/how-can-i-denote-which-input-fields-have-changed-in-angularjs)

The second answer (storing the old and current values of  the model and comparing both) does it. However, if I wanted to go with the $pristine solution I have a problem. Unchecking a ng-checked box does not change it's $pristine value. The $pristine value becomes false only by checking the box again after the uncheck.

I know I'm not suposed to use ng-model with ng-check but I get the answers from the server in values of either 1 or 0. This values used as model do not check the checkboxes.

```
ng-model="question.answer"  //will not check the box
ng-check="question.answer"  //does check the box
```

Value comes as 1 from the server. Unchecking and checking the box changes it to 'true'

```
<input ng-model="question.answer" ng-checked="question.answer" 
type="checkbox" name="{{'answer' + question.id}}"/>
```

Heres a plnkr: http://plnkr.co/edit/3xcI0Yq9WPZ1IxJJjKGt?p=preview

Answer (score 5, accepted):

What you need is to set `1` and `0` to be considered as true and false values respectively. You can use [`ng-true-value` and `ng-false-value`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/input/input%5Bcheckbox%5D) to have that set up. You dont have to deal with converting 1/0 to true/false and also can get rid of `ng-checked` and use `ng-model` itself effectively.

```
<input ng-model="question.answer" 
            ng-true-value="1" 
            ng-false-value="0" type="checkbox" name="{{'answer' + question.id}}" />
```

**[Plnkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/3YHzxm?p=preview)**

Comment: That did it, thanks. Got rid of ng-checked and $pristine is working properly