# AngularJS with components $pristine returns undefined while names are set

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope

I want to check which fields are changed in my form with `$pristine`. However, I am using AngularJS with components. I tried [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18641618/how-can-i-denote-which-input-fields-have-changed-in-angularjs) answer, but I have my names set in the form and changed `$scope.myForm` to the array with my form fields. But the console.log returns `undefined` on `value.$pristine`.

```
angular.forEach(_self.form, function(value, key) {
    if(key[0] == '$') return;
    console.log(key, value.$pristine)
});
```

`_self` reference to this so values can be set inside functions and used in the view.

How do I get the actual `$pristine` value?

**Edit:** HTML form added

```
<form>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="name">Name</label>
        <input ng-model="$ctrl.form.name" class="form-control" id="name" name="name" type="text" />
    </div>
</form>
```

Comment: Can you show the template you defined your form?

Comment: You should share the view and js code for more help.

Comment: @lenilsondc see edited question

Answer (score 1):

The `$pristine` property is not set on your model (`$ctrl.form`). It is actually set on the `ngFormController`. However, in order to have it defined on your controller, you have to define the form name on your form tag like bellow:

```
<form name="$ctrl.form">
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="name">Name</label>
        <input ng-model="$ctrl.model.name" class="form-control" id="name" name="name" type="text" />
    </div>
</form>
```

Notice that I changed `ng-model="$ctrl.form.name"` to `ng-model="$ctrl.model.name"`, because model is different than form controller. Therefore, your model has to be registered somewhere else.

> Alternatively, you can use `<div ng-form="$ctrl.form">` to bind the `ngForm` directive in a different element than `form`.

Finally, `ngForm` will bind an `ngFormController` into your controller (`this`) so that you can have access to your pristine state inside your controller like the following snippet.

```
var _self = this;

_self.$postLink = function () {
    angular.forEach(_self.form, function(value, key) {
        if(key[0] == '$') return;
        console.log(key, value.$pristine)
    });
};
```

Notice that I used the `_self.$postLink` hook, because the form will only be ready after the component link phase ended (it means child are fully linked to parent, hence `postLink`).

You can check the full working snippet bellow:

```js
angular.module('app', [])
  .component('app', {
    template: `
      <form name="$ctrl.form">
        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="name">Name</label>
            <input ng-model="$ctrl.model.name"
              type="text"
              class="form-control" 
              id="name"
              name="name"  />
        </div>
    </form>
    `,
    controller: function() {

      var _self = this;
      this.$postLink = function() {
        angular.forEach(_self.form, function(value, key) {
          if (key[0] == '$') return;
          console.log(key, value.$pristine)
        });
      };
    }
  })
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.0/angular.js"></script>
<div ng-app="app">
  <app></app>
</div>
```

Comment: Having an issue with getting the value in the input field. Will review this later, cheers anyway!

Answer (score 1):

Use `$pristine();`

```
angular.forEach(_self.form, function(value, key) {
    if(key[0] == '$') return;
    console.log(key, value.$pristine())
});
```

This is how you do it, you are missing the parenthesis. We don't use them when we are in html, but in controller we need to use them. Because we are `invoking` a function here that will `return` us a `boolean value` (true|false).

I hope, I answered your question. If you have confusion or problem then let me know. And if its your answer let me know too.